# snowflake support micro partition cluster by hour?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

the doc says support clustering by `Expressions on base columns` and has an example of using TO_DATE(timestamp) as clustering key,

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-micro-partitions.html#defining-clustering-keys-for-a-table

that indeed works as I verified, but in my case, cluster by hour is better so use this DATE_TRUNC by HOUR as cluster key

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(
  "timestamp" datetime,
  ... more fields
) CLUSTER BY (DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', "timestamp"));
```

the CREATE TABLE runs successfully, however, when loading data with COPY INTO, it says not supported within a COPY, so wonder is clustering by hour supported? or is the COPY command's limitation ? anyone knows a workaround?

```
002300 (0A000): SQL Compilation error: Function 'TRUNCTIMESTAMPTOHOUR' 
    not supported within a COPY
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Stuart's answer: just perform an INSERT INTO, SELECT FROM [staging area].

```
INSERT INTO DB.SCHEMA.T(timestamp, col2, ...)
    SELECT 
    $1::timestamp_ntz,
    $2
    ...
    FROM 
        @SOURCE.EXTRACTS/folder_location (FILE_FORMAT => '[file_format_name]', 
                                            PATTERN => '[regex file pattern]')
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try COPY into a staging table "stg" that does not have the Clustering key defined.  Then insert to the target table:

```
INSERT INTO t 
SELECT * FROM stg 
ORDER BY (DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', "timestamp"));
```